# Inserting nordic characters in database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to insert some "special" (nordic) characters in my database (MS SQL 2012).

The script itself is made with PHP, and built on CodeIgniter.

The values looks fine until they enter the database, where a starting value like **TestSæt** ends up being **TestSÃ¦t**

How to fix this? CodeIgniter is configured to use UTF-8, and the database collation is **Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS**

Comment: @JennyD: Not really.. Especially because this is MSSQL server, and not MySQL server.

Comment: Sorry about that; I blame too much blood in the caffeine stream...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Next issue then; How do you use unicode with CodeIgniter?

Comment: You ask someone who knows and cares :-) CodeIgniter = PHP web app framework = programming-related = Ask on StackOverflow.com

Comment: Lol, somehow it works now.. I have no clue what fixed it.. :)